# Proving the independecy /dependecy of the given events so as to find product of the respective probabilities

Tags: probability

The probabilities that a student passes in Mathematics, Physics and Chemistry are $m$, $p$ and $c$ respectively. Of these subjects. the student has a $75 \%$ chance of passing in atleast one, a $50 \%$ chance of passing in atleast two, and a $40 \%$ chance of passing in exactly two. Which of the following relations are true? $pmc= 1/10 , p+m+c=27/20 $ answer is both are true

> Though i got it how p+m+c=27/20 from the Venn diagram , but how do we calculate the pmc value as such we need to solve three equation with three unknowns. But it becomes trivial if the m ,p, c are independent events among themselves , so is it possible to show that ? ( I think we can give any random values instead of 75%,50%,40% will it needs to be still mutually independent ? If yes why if no why not ?

Comment: There is no reason to expect the events to be independent here.  Always be prepared for events to not be independent and be pleasantly surprised if you can show they happen to be.

Comment: Okay so the solution given online for this is totally wrong isnt Sir , i mean they even didnt even showed independecy of events isnt ? https://byjus.com/question-answer/the-probabilities-that-a-student-passes-in-mathematics-physics-and-chemistry-are-m-p-and-16/#:~:text=following%20relationsare%20true.-,The%20probabilities%20that%20a%20student%20passes%20in%20Mathematics%2C%20Physics%20and,of%20passing%20in%20exactly%20two.

Comment: So how can they used it from first step itself : @JMoravitz

Comment: I agree with $(27/20)$ computation and I also agree with both you and @JMoravitz, re independence.  You can certainly deduce that the probability that someone passed all $3$ courses is $0.5 - 0.4 = 0.1$, but all that you can deduce from that is that (for example) $$m \times p(c|m) \times p(p|c,m) = 0.1$$  Here, I am using $p(c|m)$ to denote the probability of passing Chem, given that Math has been passed, and $p(p|c,m)$ to denote the probability of passing Physics, given that Chem and Math were both passed.

Comment: Yes, the linked page is completely wrong how it did it.  Consider the following scenario: To pass anything of the three courses one must pass math and a student has a 75% chance of passing math.  If they don't pass math, then they can not possibly pass anything else.  After all, physics and chemistry are just applied math.  40% of the time they pass math and physics but not chemistry, after all chemistry is just applied math and physics.  Finally 10% of the time a student passes all three.  Here, the numbers all match what is given in the problem statement but events are clearly dependent.

Comment: With this example scenario I give, we have $m=0.75, p=0.5, c=0.1$ and we have $pmc = \frac{3}{80}\neq \frac{1}{10}$

Comment: Very very thanks @JMoravitz , user2661923.   So in conclusion only very rare cases like coin tossing ,  or phenomenon where we can absolutely observe that the events should occur naturally independent are the only possible scenarios right Sir ? And for this problem above so the answer is that **we cannot calculate the pmc value** as we have more variables than equations right Sir ?

Comment: "*we cannot calculate ___ as we have more variables than equations*"  That statement is inaccurate.  There are some scenarios where you have more variables than equations and yet are still able to find each.  As a trivial example, consider solving for $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+\dots+n^2 = 0$ over the real numbers.  You would necessarily have $a=b=c=\dots=n=0$ across the board despite having many variables and only one equation.

Comment: Oh yeah Sir missed that ,  so we need to check if those three equations leads to any possibility of solutions and if not just say cannot be determined ?

Answer (score 1):

A 75% chance of passing at least one means the chance of not passing any is 0.25. 50% chance of at least two means also 50% chance of 0 or  1, so with 0.25 chance of 0 then it's also 0.25 chance of passing 1. 50% at least two and 40% exactly two so 10% chance of passing more than two i.e. all three.

So far we have the following probabilities:

- all 3        0.1
- exactly 2    0.4
- exactly 1    0.25
- none         0.25.

Now for the algebra. I know that exam results are not likely to be independent, but we can only continue assuming independence.

0.1=mpc;

0.4=mp(1-c)+mc(1-p)+cp(1-m)=mp+mc+pc-3mpc=mp+mc+pc-3*0.1, so mp+mc+cp=0.7;

0.25=m(1-p)(1-c)+p(1-c)(1-m)+c(1-m)(1-p)=3mpc-2mp-2pc-2mc+m+p+c=0.3-2*0.7+m+p+c, so m+p+c=1.35=27/20, as required.